# Edit Item List Button Error

Tags: infopath, custom-form, list-item, edit-form

I have a list with the "Edit (link to edit item)" in the first field.

[image]

When clicked, it should open a form but instead, I get the error below

[image]

I know there isn't anything wrong with the form because I can navigate to *Item* then *Edit Item* and it works as expected. it also works in every other way I could think of. I just cannot get this button to work but I need it to.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have You inspected the detailed error behind correlation ID?

Comment: I am an end user and dont have access to the logs to see the details

Comment: Since You are facing customized solution (i assume based on Error message about the form) and do not have admin access, then most likely You will not be able to change the situation.